# No Such Attribute: Entry cn=schema cannot be modified because the attempt to update attribute objectclasses

Tags: ldap, openam, opendj

I am facing this issue while trying to upgrade Forgerock OpenAM from 13.5.2 to 14.6.4. Can anyone help as to what is the cause for this error. Does it require any changes to be done from OpenDJ side?

```
 Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main]: TransactionId[cb42ba57-6658-42db-a5c5-d2b8ac630453-30]
ERROR: An error occurred while processing /WEB-INF/template/ldif/sfha/cts-add-multivalue.ldif
org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConstraintViolationException: No Such Attribute: Entry cn=schema cannot be modified because the attempt to update attribute objectclasses would have removed one or more values from the attribute that were not present:  ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.36733.2.2.2.27 )
```

I see that the /WEB-INF/template/ldif/sfha/cts-add-multivalue.ldif below content

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.36733.2.2.1.136 NAME ( 'coreTokenMultiString01' ) DESC 'General mapped multi value string field' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15  X-ORIGIN 'ForgeRock OpenAM CTSv2' )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.36733.2.2.1.137 NAME ( 'coreTokenMultiString02' ) DESC 'General mapped multi value string field' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15  X-ORIGIN 'ForgeRock OpenAM CTSv2' )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.36733.2.2.1.138 NAME ( 'coreTokenMultiString03' ) DESC 'General mapped multi value string field' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15  X-ORIGIN 'ForgeRock OpenAM CTSv2' )
```

It would help if anyone can explain the error so that I can debug more on this.

Comment: There is no ForgeRock OpenAM 14.6.4.

Comment: We are upgrading to 14.6.4 using package from  https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/releases @BernhardThalmayr

Comment: The content of the LDIF file above is truncated. The full file is here: https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/blob/master/openam-server-only/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/template/ldif/sfha/cts-add-multivalue.ldif. Try to replace the line with just the OID with the full definition of the `frCoreToken` objectClass (as defined in the current installation, not the new value from this file).